# How to add customer "total number of orders" and "total spent" to order grid in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I am wondering how to add the following two extra colums in the order grid in magento 1.7

- Customers total number of orders
- Customers total amount spent on orders

I have managed to add the colums, but I can't get it to show any data. I believe the key to the problem is in the function *_prepareCollection()*.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the contents of any grid in Magento are contained in the collection.

Collection objects eventually resolve to a MySQL query, so in order to get them to show up in a grid you need to join that data into the collection. So long as you require them to be searchable and sortable.

You could accomplish this by joining a subselect into your collection, something like:

```
    $alias = 'subselect';
    $subselect = Mage::getModel('Varien_Db_Select', 
                Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
            )->from('sales_flat_order_grid', array(
                    'customer_id as s_customer_id', 
                    'sum(grand_total) as total_revenue', 
                    'count(*) as total_orders')
            )->group('customer_id');

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array($alias => $subselect), 
                "{$alias}.s_customer_id = main_table.customer_id");
```

In your `_prepareCollection()` call, which should override the call in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`.

Then you can define columns of `total_revenue` and `total_orders` in your `_prepareColumns()` function.

Another way to accomplish this is to turn off search and sort and call a renderer on the column, then instance a customer model and put everything together on the fly.

Comment: Thanks..Could you please specify: "In your _prepareCollection() call."

Comment: I was referring to your original question. 'I believe the key to the problem is in the function *_prepareCollection()*'. You would plug this code into your _prepareCollection function in your (overridden) Grid.php.

Comment: I tried that first, but it didn't work. But I've probably did something wrong, second try was a success :) Thanks !

Comment: I had left off the $alias assignment at first, so that might have been the issue. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

sorry need 50 reps to comment (I think) but Jonathan is referring (i hope) to the file:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Which you should extend (so not to edit the core), copy the file to:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

and edit there, the _prepareCollection() and _prepareColumns() as was suggested

add this to your _prepareCollection() function before your setCollection() call:

```
the answer from Jonathan
```

and this to your _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('total_revenue', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Revenue'),
        'index' => 'total_revenue',
        'filter_index' => 'ctotals.total_revenue',
    ));

     $this->addColumn('total_orders', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Orders'),
        'index' => 'total_orders',
        'filter_index' => 'ctotals.total_orders',
    ));
```

Comment: You're correct about the file and method. I'm working under the assumption that the block has been properly extended. That is covered in other places.

Comment: apologies i edited my response, i have run it and it works (after re compilation)

Comment: If you want to add to my answer, feel free to edit it, but to take the entirety of my answer and add it to your own seems a bit dodgy. See

Comment: See [this meta topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions).

Comment: ah i see, you're one of them.

Comment: mine was a full answer for any beginner to follow, i used your code to add to the collection, and modified it as it was missing the $alias variable, it also made no reference to the file your were editing (or overriding), i just assumed a full and complete answer was better, i actually had no idea I could edit other peoples answers (which is cool) as i'm fairly new here. :)