# how to add total number of orders to customer grid in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to show number of orders in customer grid of magento

i used this as a guide:
[How to add customer "total number of orders" and "total spent" to order grid in magento 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743178/how-to-add-customer-total-number-of-orders-and-total-spent-to-order-grid-in)

but this is a different grid

so far i have created:
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php

_prepareCollection

i added:

```
    $orderTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
            ->getTableName('sales/order');

        $collection
            ->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('orders' => $orderTableName),
                'orders.customer_id=e.entity_id',
                array('order_count' => 'COUNT(customer_id)')
            );
        $collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

before:
$this->setCollection($collection);

_prepareColumns i added:

```
$this->addColumn('order_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('# orders'),
            'index'     => 'order_count',
             'type'  => 'number'
        ));
```

while it does work in the grid, i have some problems:

- the pager shows 1 customer (should be 500+)
- sorting on this new column doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
```

And add this:

```
$collection->group('e.entity_id');
```

Overview we have:

```
$orderTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getTableName('sales/order');

    $collection
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('orders' => $orderTableName),
            'orders.customer_id=e.entity_id',
            array('order_count' => 'COUNT(customer_id)')
        );
   $collection->group('e.entity_id');
```

OR

```
$orderTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getTableName('sales/order');

    $collection
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('orders' => $orderTableName),
            'orders.customer_id=e.entity_id',
            array('order_count' => 'COUNT(customer_id)')
        )
        ->group('e.entity_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `GROUP BY` clause in your collection, and the grid pager uses `$collection->getSize()` to determine the number of pages. The problem is that `getSize()` applies a `SELECT COUNT(*)` to the collection, and fetches the first column of the first row to get the number of results. With the `GROUP BY` still applied, the pager then considers that there is only one result.

To prevent this problem, you should either use your own customers collection with a relevant `getSize()`, or use sub-queries to retrieve the totals you need.

Comment: i do understand the problem, but how can i override the getSize function?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine over there. just follow the following steps .

add code in the following file
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php

```
 add this code in _prepareCollection() fucntion only
```

---

```
$sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
        $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));
```

---

and also add this code in _prepareColumns() function with same file

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'width'     => '40px',
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'sortable' => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can create a column of total orders in customer grid table and display in numbers .
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customerlisting.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns" >
       <column name="total_orders" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TotalOrders" sortOrder="90">
           <settings>
               <dataType>text</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Total Orders</label>
               <sortable>false</sortable>
               <filter>false</filter>
           </settings>
       </column>
   </columns>
</listing>
And then create a Ui component to fetch orderdata.
Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/TotalOrders.php

<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class TotalOrders extends Column
{
   protected $orderCollectionFactory;
   /**
    * 
    * @param ContextInterface   $context           
    * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory   
    * @param array              $components        
    * @param array              $data              
    */
   public function __construct(
       ContextInterface $context,
       UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
       array $components = [],
       array $data = [],
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory  $orderCollectionFactory
   ) {

       $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
   }

   /**
    * Prepare Data Source
    *
    * @param array $dataSource
    * @return array
    */
   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
       if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
           foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
               $customerOrder = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $item['entity_id']);
               $item[$this->getData('name')] = count($customerOrder);//Value which you want to display**strong text**
           }
       }
       return $dataSource;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).